# Expand a Number Variable with comma

Tags: variables, powershell, count

How can I count in PowerShell the number of characters in a variable?
And how can I expand the value (number) in the variable with commas after each number?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$Variable = 1234567890

#Get number of characters
([string]$variable).length

10


$Variable = 1234567890

#Comma Delimit
([char[]][string]$variable) -join ','


1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
```